# Тормозит RecyclerView после refreshdata(). Android Java

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, изображения

У меня есть приложение, в котором в RecyclerView выводятся фото, при нажатии на которые открывается другая активити. Лента по типу ленты в Инстаграме.

И всё бы хорошо, но во время вызова метода refreshData() при большом количестве элементов, приложение зависает на некоторое время, зависящее от кол-ва элементов и тормозит. Вместо фото иногда проскальзывают пустые места, но со временем загружаются. Если элементов больше 100 штук где-то, то иногда намертво зависает.

Код в активити:

```
RecyclerView PostsRecycler;
...
PostsReManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 3);
PostsRecycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
....
PostsAd = new PostsRecyclerAdapter(postsData,getApplicationContext(),listener);
PostsRecycler.setLayoutManager(PostsReManager);
PostsRecycler.setAdapter(PostsAd);
```

Код адаптера:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class PostsRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostsRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public interface OnPostClickListener {
        void onItemClick(String url, String url2, String url3, String url4, ImageView mImageView);
    }

    private JSONObject userslist;
    private final OnPostClickListener listener;
    Context cont;

    public PostsRecyclerAdapter(JSONObject items, Context context, OnPostClickListener listener) {
        userslist = items;
        cont=context;
        this.listener = listener;

        //setHasStableIds(true);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.user_profile_post_item, parent, false);

        //ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
       // layoutParams.width = (int) (parent.getMeasuredWidth() * 0.72);
       // view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }




    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try {
            JSONArray arra=userslist.getJSONArray("data");
            //final JSONObject jso=arra.getJSONObject(position);
            holder.mIdView.setText(arra.getJSONObject(2+position).getString("id"));
            holder.mContentView.setText(arra.getJSONObject(2+position).getString("photo"));
            holder.mContentViewType.setText(arra.getJSONObject(2+position).getString("posttype"));
            holder.mContentViewText.setText(arra.getJSONObject(2+position).getString("posttext"));

            String type=arra.getJSONObject(2+position).getString("posttype");
            if (type.equals("GraphSidecar"))
            {
                //holder.mImageViewType.setImageDrawable(holder.mView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_photo_library_black_24dp));
                holder.mImageViewTypeGra.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mImageViewTypeVid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.mImageViewType.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
            else  if (type.equals("GraphVideo"))
            {
                holder.mImageViewType.setImageDrawable(holder.mView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_videocam_black_24dp));
                holder.mImageViewTypeGra.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.mImageViewTypeVid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mImageViewType.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                //holder.mImageViewType.setImageDrawable(holder.mView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_sync_problem_black_24dp));
                holder.mImageViewType.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.mImageViewTypeGra.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.mImageViewTypeVid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            //if (position>1 ) {
                Glide
                        .with(cont)
                        .load(arra.getJSONObject(2+position).getString("thumb"))
                        //.skipMemoryCache( true )
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
                        .override(280, 280)
                        .into(holder.mImageView);
              //  holder.mVie.setLayoutParams();
           // }

            //holder.mImageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            //final JSONObject jso=null;
            //Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
            // Do something to recover ... or kill the app.
        }

        holder.mVie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO OnItemClick Ошибка тут java.lang.NullPointerException:
                listener.onItemClick( holder.mIdView.getText().toString(), holder.mContentView.getText().toString(), holder.mContentViewType.getText().toString(), holder.mContentViewText.getText().toString() ,holder.mImageView );
            }
        });

    }

    public void refreshData(JSONObject newlist){

        //Чистим коллекцию с данными
        //userslist.remove("data");

        //наполняем измененными данными
        userslist=newlist;

        //передергиваем адаптер
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        try {
            JSONArray arra = userslist.getJSONArray("data");
            if (arra.length()>0) return arra.length()-3;
            else return 0;
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final LinearLayout mVie;
        public final TextView mIdView;
        public final TextView mContentView;
        public final TextView mContentViewType;
        public final TextView mContentViewText;
        public final ImageView mImageView;
        public final ImageView mImageViewType;
        public final ImageView mImageViewTypeGra;
        public final ImageView mImageViewTypeVid;
        //public DummyItem mItem;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mVie = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.post);
            mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.PostUrl);
            mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.PostPhotoUrl);
            mContentViewType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.PostTypeSt);
            mContentViewText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.PostTextSt);
            mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.PostImageView);
            mImageViewType = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.PostImageViewType);
            mImageViewTypeGra = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.PostImageViewTypeGra);
            mImageViewTypeVid = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.PostImageViewTypeVid);
        }

        /*@Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
        }*/
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PostActivity">
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/scrollpost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".UserProfileActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_user_profile">


       <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/posts_rel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/story_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/prf_reltitle1"
            tools:listitem="@layout/search_item">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
  </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Layout элементов RecyclerView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/post"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PostUrl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="placeforurl" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PostPhotoUrl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="placeforphotourl" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PostTypeSt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="placeforphotourl" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PostTextSt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="placeforphotourl" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/PostImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="Image"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_sync_problem_black_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/PostImageViewType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:contentDescription="Image"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/PostImageViewTypeGra"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:contentDescription="Image"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_library_black_24dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/PostImageViewTypeVid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:contentDescription="Image"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_videocam_black_24dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Понимаю, код не идеален.
Используется Glide для загрузки фото из сети по АПИ.

Хотелось бы узнать, как можно это дело оптимизировать, в чём ошибка? Фото не шибко большие, тумбинейлы обычные в сетку по 3 в одной линии.

В идеале нужна бесконечно листаемая лента. Как этого лучше всего добиться? Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Можно посмотреть в сторону pagging library от гугла что бы загружать , допустим по 20 штук

Answer (score 0):

Все потому что у вас не работает кэш `RecyclerView`, в данном случае потому, что все элементы, включая `RecyclerView`, завернуты в `ScrollView`. И вместо того чтобы отрисовать или перерисовать только видимые элементы `RecyclerView`, происходит перерисовка всех элементов, т.е. они все помещаются в оперативную память, и по каждому View происходит запрос на картинку. Если ничего не менять, приложение может падать с ошибкой нехватки памяти.
Откажитесь от `ScrollView`, и посмотрите результат.
p.s. вам нужно искать другой способ, чтобы скрывать `ToolBar`при скроллинге.

Comment: Спасибо! Но есть небольшая проблема) Мне нужно два RecyclerViews в одном макете. Одна маленькая горизонталь, а в моем примере выше - большая вертикаль

Comment: Все зависит от того, куда нужно засунуть второй `RV`. Можно для отдельного `ViewHolder`, например первого или последнего элемента, применить отдельный вид элемента, т.е. вывести другой `RV`. Можно и по другому, все зависит от того, что именно вам нужно. В любом случае, это уже отдельный вопрос.